# Managing large external dependencies using mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am working on a project which makes use of several large 3rd party libraries such as boost, tbb and ACE. I would like to control exactly which versions of these 3rd party libraries are used in my project rather than rely on whatever is available in the build machine. I have done this sort of thing in the past by adding these libraries to my projects repository. This works fine but it does slow mercurial down forcing it to track a couple orders of magnitude more files than what my project contains. Is there a better to way to manage  external dependencies?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you can find Mercurial, git, or svn repos for those libraries, you can make them [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) of your project.  Subrepos don't point to a repo in general, but rather point to a specific version of a specfiic repo, so it meets your goal on that.

Answer (score 1):

For large *binary* dependencies, I would recommend externalizing those in an artifact repository, outside of any VCS (especially a *distributed* VCS where you are cloning around huge repository because of versioned binaries).

Java has Nexus, C++/C# can [publish an artifact](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) in a [NuGet repo](http://docs.nuget.org/).
That would be preferable that trying to store everything in a DVCS repo (Mercurial or Git).

Comment: I thought about that but it gets messy when you have multiple branches. You do not necessarily want to upgrade your external dependencies in all branches at the same time (thik dev vs qa branch)

Comment: @Samwise: you don't have to upgrade in *all* branches when managing external dependencies: your configuration file (the equivalent of the pom.xml) can have different content (i.e. different version numbers for the dependencies it declares) per branch.